# Kinesis Stream CloudFormation template fails when using RetentionPeriodHours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-cloudformation

According to the cloud formation [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesis-stream.html), you can add RetentionPeriodHours as an integer in your template. However when I do, the creation fails. I have tried using serverless, and I have used the AWS console to upload the template file. Both fail with

> Encountered unsupported property RetentionPeriodHours

To be clear: the creation works just fine if I remove the RetentionPeriodHours setting. I know you can update the retention period after creation using the CLI, but for my use I'd really like to be able to do it on creation.

Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: How can anyone answer this question? You've just said `it fails` and not even bothered to say HOW it fails or what error the message is.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: Oops! Yeah, that would be helpful wouldn't it? Updated :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for an answer to this: AWS docs were updated right after I posted this, and RetentionPeriodHours is no longer listed as a valid property. So the answer to my question is: you can't set this in a CF template.